# Vue how to send index from v-for to method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to pass the index of a v-for so i can change some values, i'm adding the doctor team members dynamically and i have this file input to add their image, although when i add doctors it only changes the first's one image because it always sends index of the first doctor, the file input is inside the v-for loop if that helps.

```
<v-file-input
    hide-input 
    class="d-none" 
    id="doctorImage"
    truncate-length="1" 
    @change="doctorImage($event, index, doctor)"
></v-file-input>
```

Method:

```
doctorImage(e, index, doctor) {
    console.log(index)
    this.doctors[index] = {
        image: URL.createObjectURL(e),
        imageData: e,
        name: doctor.name, 
        specialty: doctor.specialty
    }
    this.doctorChange += 1   
}
```

The index is always 0, although it displays the index number when i create it dynamically on the doctor's card, why is that happening?

Comment: You need to include your `v-for` in the snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [List Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html) using v-for.

```
<div ... v-for="(doctor, index) in doctors" ... >
  {{ index }} // you can use index
  ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i fixed the issue, that happened because i had a label for doctorImage and the file input id was doctorImage also inside the v-for statement, that made multiple same id's and created a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I iterate with a limit. Example
If the data were:

```
{
    limit: 3,
    currentIndex: 2,
    listData:[{name:'Data1'},{name:'Data2'},{name:'Data3'},{name:'Data4'},{name:'Data5'}]
}
```

In the .vue file it would be the following

```
<span v-for="index in limit" v-bind:key="index">
   {{listData[index+currentIndex].name}}
</span>
```

I make sure that you control that the sum **index + currentIndex** does not exceed the limit of your data